# How to convert op to query in jena?

Tags: jena

My code is:

```
String s="";//some query
Query query = QueryFactory.create(s);
Op op = Algebra.compile(query) ;
op = Algebra.optimize(op) ;
```

How can I convert the op back to query? I tried:

```
query=OpAsQuery.asQuery(op);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Please show the query and say what "does not work" means.  
`OpAsQuery` does not always work after optimization. Some optimized forms can't be written in standard SPARQL. It does not "unoptimize".

Comment: SELECT ?s ?o  {?s ?p ?o.FILTER(?s=<http://eo.dbpedia.org/resource/Utrecht> ||?s=<http://eo.dbpedia.org/resource/Israelo>)}